# Parse a Set<String> and Create a new Set<String> based on a Common Delimiter

Tags: java

I'm trying to take a Set of Strings and convert them like below using the most efficient algorithm possible.  Any ideas?

```
Set<String> directoryList = new HashSet<String>() {
      {
        add("a/a1/a2/a3");
        add("b/b1/b2/b3");
        add("c/c1/c2/c3/c4");
      }
    };

    //need construct a new Set<String> which contains:
    a
    a/a1
    a/a1/a2
    a/a1/a2/a3
    b
    b/b1
    b/b1/b2
    b/b1/b2/b3
    c
    c/c1
    c/c1/c2
    c/c1/c2/c3
    c/c1/c2/c3/c4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try in this way

```
  Set<String> directoryList = new HashSet<String>() {
        {
            add("a/a1/a2/a3");
            add("b/b1/b2/b3");
            add("c/c1/c2/c3/c4");
        }
    };

    Set<String> newSet=new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for(String i:directoryList){
        String[] str=i.split("/");
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        for(String s:str){
            sb.append(s);
            newSet.add(sb.toString());
            sb.append("/");
        }
    }
```

Out put by running

```
    for(String st:newSet){
        System.out.println(st);
    }
```

Is

```
a
a/a1
a/a1/a2
a/a1/a2/a3
b
b/b1
b/b1/b2
b/b1/b2/b3
c
c/c1
c/c1/c2
c/c1/c2/c3
c/c1/c2/c3/c4
```

Comment: the LinkedHashSet is for natural ordering correct?  Any advantage of using the LinkedHashSet vs a TreeSet?  Both seem to order it naturally (a, a/a1, a/a1/a2..etc)

Comment: also update your answer to be LinkedHashSet<String> instead of LinkedHashSet<> as that causes a compile error in java 1.6

Comment: @c12 yes `LinkedHashSet` for keep order. `TreeSet` is implemented using a tree structure(red-black tree in algorithm book). The elements in a set are `sorted`, but the add, remove, and contains methods has  time complexity of `O(log (n))`. It offers several methods to deal with the ordered set like first(), last(), headSet(), tailSet(), etc.  `LinkedHashSet` is between `HashSet` and `TreeSet`. It is implemented as a hash table with a `linked list` running through it, so it provides the order of insertion. The time complexity of basic methods is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

This is another way that I came up with it, so hope it helps, I just solved it for one case, and I am sure you know how to expand it.

```
 public class LetterExtraction {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> directoryList = new TreeSet<String>() {
            {
                add("a-a1-a2-a3");
                add("b-b1-b2-b3");
                add("c-c1-c2-c3-c4");
            }
        };

        for (String s : directoryList) {

            //String s = "a-a1-a2-a3-a4";
            String outCome = "";
            char[] c = s.toCharArray();
            char ch = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                if (c[i] == '-') {
                    System.out.print(outCome);
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    outCome += c[i];
                } else {
                    outCome += c[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println(outCome);
        }
    }
}
```

out come:

```
a
a-a1
a-a1-a2
a-a1-a2-a3
b
b-b1
b-b1-b2
b-b1-b2-b3
c
c-c1
c-c1-c2
c-c1-c2-c3
c-c1-c2-c3-c4
```

Comment: I could not figure it out why it starts from c not a ?

Comment: It starts from c because HashSet is not sorted. Try with TreeSet.